# Why does Visual Studio not reflect the correct version of the application?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

In Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition, in the My Project tab, the version is shown as in this picture:

[alt text http://ffcb9q.bay.livefilestore.com/y1p8ub58mi4s2EEkIjILE9K8LfaTO2Xe1LK0qKoSDN97ENRUmKsLr7DxjAO91PPgVdPcVv-SeDb1Y2lKJTRuRGb2gPkZK63mAwf/Publish%20Version.PNG](http://ffcb9q.bay.livefilestore.com/y1p8ub58mi4s2EEkIjILE9K8LfaTO2Xe1LK0qKoSDN97ENRUmKsLr7DxjAO91PPgVdPcVv-SeDb1Y2lKJTRuRGb2gPkZK63mAwf/Publish%20Version.PNG)

But when I run this code:

```
MsgBox(My.Application.Info.Version.ToString)
```

It just shows 1.0.0.0

Comment: Are you sure that the code has successfully compiled and you are not starting an outdated version?

Comment: I am sure. I have seen it two consecutive times.

Comment: I have an application where I have seen this, but only when I choose Start Without Debugging. The only reason I noticed is I put the version number and connection string dump on the About screen. (This is an internal line of business application that connects to different servers based on the Active Directory information for load balancing and bandwidth... I peek at that screen to ensure we are connecting as expected).

Comment: @Godeke, Yes, the version is supposed to update on the about screen.

Answer (score 0):

The "Publish" tab is completely separate from the concept of incremental builds updating the generated assembly information.

Could you take a look at your AssemblyInfo.vb file? I bet the numbers defined in there are different.

Comment: What is the use of having the "Publish Version" section under the Publish tb if whatever is written there is not taken into account?